# Nothing happen while downloading xml file from server in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

This method connect given path which has to be xml file and save xml file to somewhere in server. Finally, download xml file from server by calling _downloadFileFromServer method

```
public async Task SaveFiletoServer(int id, string nud_preparationValue, int nud_divideNumber, string saveConfigPath, string saveConfigName)
{
    try
    {
        await tryToConnect(id, nud_preparationValue, nud_divideNumber);
        ReadXml.Save(XDocument,saveConfigPath,saveConfigName, nud_divideNumber);
        await _downloadFileFromServer(saveConfigPath, saveConfigName);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.DownloadError = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

this method is using by above method(Download xml file from server).

```
private async Task _downloadFileFromServer(string saveConfigPath, string saveConfigName)
{
    var memory = new MemoryStream();
    using (var stream = new FileStream(string.Concat(saveConfigPath,saveConfigName,".xml"), FileMode.Open))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memory);
    }
    memory.Position = 0;
    await Task.FromResult(File(memory, "application/xml",string.Concat(saveConfigName,".xml")));
}
```

If I directly call _downloadFileFromServer method, it works correctly.xml file is downloading. However, when I call SaveFiletoServer method, _downloadFileFromServer method doesn't work correctly. Xml file is not downloading. I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling with same parameters? No error is happing?

Try to use `await method.ConfigureAwait(false);` on task methos with await

Comment: yeah I'm sure that I checked with breakpoint. Yes, there is no error but not working. I tried to use your advise but not worked.

Comment: And the place that you call `SaveFiletoServer` is awaitable?

Comment: I'm using ajax for that. like below :
<code>
                $.ajax({
                    url: "XmlApi/DownloadFileAsync/" + $(this)[0].id + "?nud_preparationValue=" + nud_preparationValue + "&nud_divideNumber=" + nud_divideNumber + "&saveConfigPath=" + saveConfigPath + "&saveConfigName=" + saveConfigName,
                    type: "GET",</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by using html.actionlink instead of ajax in order to download xml file with SaveFiletoServer method